# Handlebar js on click is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9dw33wx6/)

Hi,

I have to make a simple click for dynamically loaded data from json for anchor tag. i tried doing both the way with vanila js and with jquery both the way iam not able to achieve it. not sure what's the issue here. same function is triggering for normal added html

```
{{#pagination info.page.current_page info.page.per_page info.page.total_result_count}}
    <div id="pagination" class="pagination">{{#unless startFromFirstPage}}
        <a href="#">&lt;</a> {{/unless}} {{#each pages}} {{#if isCurrent}} [
        <a href="#">{{page}}</a> ] {{/if}} {{#unless isCurrent}}
        <a href="#">{{page}}</a> {{/unless}} {{/each}} {{#unless endAtLastPage}}
        <a href="#">&gt;</a> {{/unless}}
    </div>
    {{/pagination}}


var results = {};
var pageNum = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    getResult(1);
    document.getElementById('results').firstElementChild('.pagination').onclick = function () {
        var pageNum = $(this).text();
        getResult(pageNum);
        alert('hi ' + pageNum);
    }

    function getResult(pageNum) {
        $.getJSON('searchResult-' + pageNum + '.json', function (data) {
            var compileResult = Handlebars.compile($("#result").html());
            fullResult = compileResult(data);
            $("#results").html(fullResult);
        });
    }
});
```

Iam not able to json data..

so here it is///

```
{
  "record_count": 5,
  "records": {
    "page": [
      {
        "body": "A Post in May This post is in the middle of the other ones, so we can show date range filtering with published_at.",
        "external_id": "c1173561bd0641bf0f5bd64c4d4d5a68939552c4",
        "sections": [
          "A Post in May"
        ],
        "title": "A Post in May",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-25T06:40:27Z",
        "image": "",
        "type": "post",
        "url": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/2012/05/01/a-post-in-may.html",
        "popularity": 1,
        "published_at": "2012-05-01T07:00:00Z",
        "info": "",
        "_index": "crawled",
        "_type": "page",
        "_score": 1,
        "_version": null,
        "_explanation": null,
        "sort": null,
        "highlight": {
          "title": "A <em>Post</em> in May",
          "sections": "A <em>Post</em> in May",
          "body": "A <em>Post</em> in May This post is in the middle of the other ones, so we can show date range filtering with published_at."
        },
        "id": "5025a3036052f6b650000008"
      },
      {
        "body": "First Post! Here is the first post on my site.",
        "external_id": "9508ace2e1ba669854eb49fbe9429952ff1a6d4c",
        "sections": [
          "First Post!"
        ],
        "title": "First Post!",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-25T06:40:27Z",
        "image": "",
        "type": "post",
        "url": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/2012/01/01/first-post.html",
        "popularity": 1,
        "published_at": "2012-01-01T08:00:00Z",
        "info": "",
        "_index": "crawled",
        "_type": "page",
        "_score": 1,
        "_version": null,
        "_explanation": null,
        "sort": null,
        "highlight": {
          "title": "First <em>Post</em>!",
          "sections": "First <em>Post</em>!",
          "body": "First <em>Post</em>! Here is the first post on my site."
        },
        "id": "5025a3036052f6b650000006"
      },
      {
        "body": "A post with an image This post has a photo. If you look at the metadata, it has an st:image meta tag. This meta tag displays the image as a thumbnail in search results.",
        "external_id": "92941161a37a99df8a74040c8a0061cfc266eeec",
        "sections": [
          "A post with an image"
        ],
        "title": "A post with an image",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-25T06:40:27Z",
        "image": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/images/cat.jpg",
        "type": "post",
        "url": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/2012/08/10/post-with-image.html",
        "popularity": 1,
        "published_at": "2012-08-10T07:00:00Z",
        "info": "",
        "_index": "crawled",
        "_type": "page",
        "_score": 3.8706326,
        "_version": null,
        "_explanation": null,
        "sort": null,
        "highlight": {
          "title": "A <em>post</em> with an image",
          "sections": "A <em>post</em> with an image",
          "body": "A <em>post</em> with an image This post has a photo. If you look at the metadata, it has an st:image meta tag. This meta tag displays the image as a thumbnail in search results."
        },
        "id": "5025a3036052f6b650000004"
      },
      {
        "body": "Swiftype Crawler Demo Site Welcome to the Swiftype Crawler Demo Site. Be sure to check out the source code to view the Swiftype meta tags that control how the crawler works. A post with an image A Post in May First Post! Learn more About this site.",
        "external_id": "3fccec2102880d859c1cf8f8b60609e62c7ab50b",
        "sections": [
          "Swiftype Crawler Demo Site"
        ],
        "title": "Swiftype Crawler Demo Site",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-25T06:39:41Z",
        "image": "",
        "type": "page",
        "url": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/",
        "popularity": 1,
        "published_at": "2017-06-28T06:39:54Z",
        "info": "",
        "_index": "crawled",
        "_type": "page",
        "_score": 0.009990831,
        "_version": null,
        "_explanation": null,
        "sort": null,
        "highlight": {
          "body": "Welcome to the Swiftype Crawler Demo Site. Be sure to check out the source code to view the Swiftype meta tags that control how the crawler works. A <em>post</em> with an image A Post in May First Post! Learn more About this site."
        },
        "id": "5025a3036052f6b650000002"
      },
      {
        "body": "About This Site This site is used for demonstrating the Swiftype Crawler. As you can see from the source code of this page, it has a st:type meta tag with a value of page as opposed to post. This allows filtering of blog posts from regular pages.",
        "external_id": "261733cee3ca9c280320efc0d79ad8566ddbb9a9",
        "sections": [
          "About This Site"
        ],
        "title": "About This Site",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-25T06:40:27Z",
        "image": "",
        "type": "page",
        "url": "http://crawler-demo-site.herokuapp.com/about.html",
        "popularity": 1,
        "published_at": "2017-06-28T06:40:31Z",
        "info": "",
        "_index": "crawled",
        "_type": "page",
        "_score": 0.0057682088,
        "_version": null,
        "_explanation": null,
        "sort": null,
        "highlight": {
          "body": "for demonstrating the Swiftype Crawler. As you can see from the source code of this page, it has a st:type meta tag with a value of page as opposed to <em>post</em>. This allows filtering of blog posts from regular pages."
        },
        "id": "5025a3046052f6b65000000a"
      }
    ]
  },
  "info": {
    "page": {
      "query": "post",
      "current_page": 1,
      "num_pages": 1,
      "per_page": 20,
      "total_result_count": 5,
      "facets": {}
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}
```

Comment: `getJSON` is an [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) process, so what's happening in your code is that you're adding an event listener to a non-existent element. To fix this place the event listener addition logic inside `getJSON`'s `success` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for other Developers, if facing same issue, i have fixed it by adding document then on click event binding.

var results = {};
var pageNum = 1;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getResult(1);
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function () {
        //alert('hi ' + pageNum);
        var pageNum = $(this).text();
        getResult(pageNum);  
    });

    function getResult(pageNum) {
        $.getJSON('searchResult-' + pageNum + '.json', function (data) {
            var compileResult = Handlebars.compile($("#result").html());
            fullResult = compileResult(data);
            $("#results").html(fullResult);
        });
    }
});
```